# Installation of Ubuntu 14.04 shows error about /boot/efi and takes forever

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, system-installation

I'm trying without success to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my Toshiba Portege.

I want to remove Windows 7 and I tried with the automatic partitioning from the USB installer (I found that compared to previous Ubuntu's version it is getting more complicated).

When it finally started installing (first time without any bar of progress, very annoying, then I shut down and tried again and the progress was shown), it is stack on

```
Creating ext4 file system for / in partition #2 of SCI1 (0,0,0) (sda)
```

and in the details there are many errors like

```
/usr/lib/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:18: Source ID 86689 was not found when attempting to remove it Glib.source_remove(self.timeout).
```

I let it run all the night but it is still there.

I also got the error:

```
The attempt to mount a file system with type vfat in SCSI2 (0,0,0), partition #1 (sda) at /boot/efi failed
You may resume partitioning from the partitioning menu.
```

Answer (score 3):

I managed to install Ubuntu, even if not to get the process bar. However it was so quick that I didn't need it!

The error

```
The attempt to mount a file system with type vfat in SCSI2 (0,0,0), partition #1 (sda) at /boot/efi failed
You may resume partitioning from the partitioning menu.
```

led me to [this post on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2021534), where I discovered that what I needed to do was reduce the size of the EFI partition, which cannot be more than 256MB, apparently. I set mine to 200 MB, and the installation went fine afterwards.