# Installer is taking a long time (Over 10 hours)

Tags: partitioning

I'm attempting to install Ubuntu 16 on my 128 GB flash drive.  In order to do this, I am using an 8 GB drive to act as the live USB.  I made the 8 GB drive live by using the recommended program, Rufus.  Also, I have tried using Lili as well.

I have partitioned the 128 GB drive to be sdx1 4GB FAT32 mount /UDISK, sdx5 12 GB Ext4 mount /, sdx6 16GB swap, the rest is unallocated.

I set the installer to sdx5 Ext4 and used sdx (my 128 GB USB) as the boot installer.

The installation log keeps moving along, but I'm not sure it's making any progress...

The installer log basically says over and over again:

```
Glib.source_remove(self.timeout_id)
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:18 (or 131): Warning: Source ID xxxxxx was not found when attempting to remove it
```

That source id has gotten all the way up to 159,171.

Is the installation just being slow, or is it stuck in a loop? Or did I do something incorrectly?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It should be done within a few minutes. So something is wrong. Please tell us more about the computer (brand name and model, graphics card name and model). What USB drives are you using (brand name and model)? Which iso file is it. I recommend the first point releiase, 16.04.1 LTS. Did you check with md5sum in linux (or Md5summer in Windows) that the iso file was correctly downloaded?

Comment: Possibly related: [Installation of Ubuntu 14.04 shows error about /boot/efi and takes forever](https://askubuntu.com/q/590533/301745)