# Repeated issues with installing 16.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, lenovo

I have been attempting to dual-boot Ubuntu 16.04 with Windows 10 on my Lenovo IdeaPad 320. I have been following [this guide](https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/). I have been able to follow the steps outlined until I reach the point of Ubuntu installing, when I am met with several error messages during the installation of grub2.

These error messages read:

```
usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:18: Warning: Source ID XXXXX was not found when attempting to remove it
```

Anyone know how to remedy this?

Comment: It doesn't sound like an issue during the grub installation, more like the GUI experiencing a problem. But it's a "Warning" not an "Error" so it should continue, maybe with issues. What happens after this appears?

Comment: Does it say "Source ID XXXXX" verbatim, or are you using "XXXXX" to represent a number?

Comment: [This bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1426981) might be related. How much disk space and memory do you have? Are you installing Ubuntu in French? Are there any "Gtk-CRITICAL" or "GLib-CRITICAL" errors?

Comment: Possibly related: [Installation of Ubuntu 14.04 shows error about /boot/efi and takes forever](https://askubuntu.com/q/590533/301745)

Comment: It does not say "Source ID XXXXX"-  for example, it can read "Source ID 32177" or "32117", etc. After this, the next line is "Glib.source_remove(self.rows_changed_id). Then, five instances of "Gtk-message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar""